# VB Calendar - Populate with mysql events table

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, calendar

I have a table with dates in mysql that I want to populate a vb calendar with as events, or "active" days.

Using a sql statement with something like

```
Select event, date FROM dateTable WHERE event = eventType.SelectedValue
```

how do I put these as events on my calender

```
<asp:Calendar runat="server" id="calendar1"></asp:calendar>
```

I'm sure I use data:repeater in some way I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [MSDN's article on Displaying Selected Dates From a Database in the Calendar Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228044%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

The modifications you'd need are:

- swapping out the SQL Server (`System.Data.SqlClient`)code with the [MySQL Connector for .NET](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) (or your favorite MySQL library for .NET).
- suggested improvements might be scrapping the DataSet, and go with a local MySqlDataReader instead